# GTK3, Pango - rendering mixed case text as uppercase in TextView?

Tags: python, gtk3, pango

What would be the most efficient way to render text, which in the `TextBuffer` could be any case, as uppercase in a `TextView`?

It isn't for the entirety of the text, only specific styles within it - and the original capitalization of that section needs to be preserved in case the user changes the text style back to a non-capitalized style.

So if the relevant section of text could be tagged with a `TextTag` that would be ideal, but there isn't a tag to fully capitalize (there is a small_caps font variant, which for some reason doesn't seem to work in a textview) - can one create a custom TextTag property like "all_caps" and, if so, how would it be implemented?

Other thoughts would be overriding the textview draw function (sounds painful) or possibly creating a secondary `TextBuffer` and changing the text case on the fly?

UPDATE:

For this application, the best would likely be to intercept the string being passed to `Pango` from the `TextBuffer` (from `TextView`'s `do_draw`, I *think*) and change it on the fly: for other text styles in this application, some additional text character additions would be needed (It's a screenwriting application, so there is a 'Parenthical' style which, unsurprisingly, is always contained in parentheses - these should be added as part of the style, not relying on the user to add them)

So the updated question would be: How would one subclass / monkey code / something `Pango` / `PangoCairo` / `Gtk+ 3` to intercept the string being passed to `Pango` (along with its `TextTags`) so as to alter / add to it according to its `TextTag` styles?

Comment: Really good question and I don't think it's possible in an easy way currently. Pango doesn't support changing the case of text (not listed [here](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html)), but a solution would probably involve adding that functionality to Pango and then exposing it in GtkTextTag.

Comment: thanks @ptomato - edited question with a specific direction to aim towards...